# Is it necessary to Initialize / Declare variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, initialization, declaration

Is it necessary to initialize / declare a variable before a loop or a function?

Whether I initialize / declare variable before or not my code still works.

I'm sharing demo code for what I actually mean:

```
$cars = null;

foreach ($build as $brand) {
     $cars .= $brand . ",";
}

echo $cars;
```

Or

```
foreach ($build as $brand) {
     $cars .= $brand . ",";
}

echo $cars;
```

Both pieces of code works same for me, so is it necessary to initialize / declare a variable at the beginning?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

PHP does not require it, but it is a good practice to always initialize your variables.

If you don't initialize your variables with a default value, the PHP engine will do a type cast depending on how you are using the variable. This sometimes will lead to unexpected behaviour.

So in short, in my opinion, always set a default value for your variables.

P.S.
In your case the value should be set to "" (empty string), instead of null, since you are using it to concatenate other strings.

*Edit*

As others (@n-dru) have noted, if you don't set a default value a notice will be generated.

Comment: Null and empty ""... aren't they same?

Comment: No, they are not the same. One is of type string, the other is null.
You can see the difference when playing around with the is_null function.

`is_null($null) // Returns true and generates a notice`
`empty("") // Returns true`

Comment: So you mean NULL = Unassigned and "" = an empty STRING?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as unassigned variables in PHP.  Variables are created the first time you use them. If you use a variable that is not yet created it has a null value by default.  
"" is an empty string yes.  

You should be aware that the [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function returns true in a couple of cases (empty string, false, null, unexisting variable).

Comment: Since PHP 8 If you don't set a default value a "warning" will be generated!
More details:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php

Answer (score 21):

You had better assign it an empty string `$cars = '';`, otherwise (in case you have error reporting on) you should see a notice:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: cars

PHP will assume it was empty and the resultant string will be the same, but you should prefer not to cause an extra overhead caused by a need of logging that Notice. So **performance**-wise it is better to assign it empty first.

Besides, using editors like Aptana, etc, you may wish to press `F3` to see where given variable originated from. And it is so comfortable to have it initialized somewhere. So **debugging**-wise it is also better to have obvious place of the variable's birth.

Answer (score 0):

It depends: If you declare a variable outside a function, it has a "global scope", that means it can only be accessed outside of a function.

If a variable is declared inside a function, it has a "local scope" and can be used only inside that function.
     (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

But it seems that the variable "cars" that you defined outside the function works for your function even without the global keyword...

Comment: firstly note that there is no function declared in the code posted. So, there is no scope of having `global` keyword. You should understand what is asked before answering a question. Also what you have written is quite misleading. I would ask you to refer to http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php to understand php variables.