# How insert associative array inside another array? PHP

Tags: php

Why I can't insert an associative array inside another array? How can I do that? [PHP]

I try get somenthing like this:

```
    [0] => ['name' => 'namedperson' , 'type' => 'text' ,'id'=>'ahushaus29293' ]  
    [1] => [...] 
    ...
```

Example:

```
public function getArrayWithCustomFields($boardId, $client){
    $customFields = $client->getBoardCustomFields($boardId);
    foreach($customFields as $customField){
        array_push($array_custom_fields, array('name' => $customField->name, 'type' => $customField->type, 'id' => $customField->id));
    }
    return $array_custom_fields;
}
```

Comment: @ArSeN They're not trying to merge arrays, they want a 2-dimensional array. I think their code should work.

Comment: Assuming `$customFields` is an array of objects.

Comment: Oooh I see, first part was just edited in later. Sorry about that

Comment: @ArSeN I just fixed the formatting, I didn't change it.

Comment: My bad! @OP - what result are you getting instead of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please show the result of `var_dump($customFields);`

Comment: that's error : TypeError
array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given

Comment: var_dump : array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1395 (9) { ["id"]=> string(24) "5fea1c1bba6a191f192a2855" ["idModel"]=> string(24) "5fe9e5143ce2e5821e4e2cb0" ["modelType"]=> string(5) "board" ["fieldGroup"]=> string(64) "6e8795d430ab96ea08e838e29dc18549ba70077c74cd4cce84c047792c7b5141" ["display"]=> object(stdClass)#1397 (1) { ["cardFront"]=> bool(true) } ["name"]=> string(4) "Nome" ["pos"]=> int(16384) ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["isSuggestedField"]=> bool(false) } ...

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `$array_custom_fields`, as well as, check if the returned value from `getBoardCustomFields` is an array.

```php
public function getArrayWithCustomFields($boardId, $client)
{
    // Init the array
    $array_custom_fields = [];
    $customFields = $client->getBoardCustomFields($boardId);

    // Check if the returned value from $client->getBoardCustomFields() is an array.
    if (is_array($customFields))
    {
        foreach($customFields as $customField) {
            array_push(
                $array_custom_fields,
                [
                    'name' => $customField->name,
                    'type' => $customField->type,'id' => $customField->id
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    return $array_custom_fields;
}
```

P.S: it's a good practice to always initialize your variables in PHP even tho it doesn't force you to do it.

Comment: awesome! please consider to mark this question as answered! thanks

Comment: Why "it's a good practice to always initialize your variables in PHP"? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955639/is-it-necessary-to-initialize-declare-variable-in-php

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.